# App drawer replacement with list view and letter shortcuts for Android

Tags: android

I am looking for an app drawer replacement with list view for Android 4.4.2. The list view should provide letter shortcuts, just like Android 4.1.2's default app drawer used to have (see red rectangle in the following screenshot):

[image]

[AppDrawer (MIUI App Drawer)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=JakedUp.AppDrawer&hl=en) doesn't have letter shortcuts:

[image]

If possible:

- customizable font/icon sizes as well as row spacing
- can uninstall app from drawer
- can create shortcut for any app
- compatible with [Nova Launcher Prime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime&hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Quad Drawer, quick app drawer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levelup.quad&hl=en)

Quad Drawer (0.99 USD) is the quickest way to launch apps. It’s a simple app drawer: using the predictive keyboard, just type a few letters of the app you’re looking for and Quad will bring it to you.

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (second with an alphabetical list; click images to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, nice app! I'm just missing the letter shortcuts though :/

Comment: Glad that my answer helped you :)